# Excel VBA extract values from nested function

Tags: excel, vba, function, nested

Is it possible to extract the resulting value of a nested sub-function in VBA?

For example, from this INDEX-MATCH look-up function, I would like to find the value from the results from the two `MATCH()` functions:

```
=+INDEX(Sheet3!$B$5:$I$15;MATCH($A6;Sheet3!$A$5:$A$15;0);1)
```

I am looking for a macro that can return the value of the nested `MATCH()` function as an input in a VBA code. That is, I realize I could extract the `MATCH()` subfunction and have VBA paste it as a value. What I want is identify the value of the `MATCH()` function and calculate with it within my VBA script.

Comment: You are probably looking for the `LOOKUP` function then, if you want the value instead of the row number?

Answer (score 1):

As I'm not quite following what you're saying, I'll take a guess... you want to use the match() scenario separately?

```
dim x as long, y as long, z as string
x = application.match($A" & ActiveCell & ",Sheet3!$A$5:$A$15,0)"
y = x*3 'perform some work using the row number x, knowing match of 1 = row 5 on sheet3
z = application.index(Sheet3!$B$5:$I$15," & y & ")"
```

Took that a step further where you can utilize said arithmetic'd match value.

---

Inherently, the match only provides a row number from your array, so i don't know what the "extract" you are referring to would be.  If you are looking to extract a value that you're matching to, then you'll just end up with what is (from your example) in A6.

---

**Edit:** Updating code to be usable (previously just gave a concept)

```
dim x as long, y as long, z as string
with sheets("Sheets3")
    x = application.match(ActiveCell.value,.range(.cells(5,"A"),.cells(15,"A")),0)
    y = x*1 'perform some work using the row number x, knowing match of 1 = row 5 on sheet3
    z = application.index(.range(.cells(5,"B"),.cells(15,"B")),y)  'This index was changed to be a SINGLE COLUMN (was B5:I15)
end with
```

Comment: At least 2 double quotes `"` are missing somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ changed it up to be more useful and all fit within VBA, not pasting a formula.